# Can I show an analog clock in Linux terminal?

Tags: linux

I know that by Linux tmux I can show a digital clock in terminal. But how to show an analog clock in terminal? Is it possible?

Comment: Do you want to write such a program or are you just searching around for one?

Comment: You can google around and hit http://www.tenox.tc/out/ or http://kmandla.wordpress.com/2009/12/26/an-analog-clock-for-the-console/

Comment: Just searching one for use, digital clock is not intuitive

Comment: There's a package called tty-clock - if it's not intuitive, than make so that it becomes intuitive.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming problems, not general discussions or program recommendations. This question may fit better at Superuser.com or your regular Linux forum.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look at [aclock](http://www.tenox.tc/out/).

> Aclock is an analog clock program for text mode console displays, terminals, or terminal emulators. This program is obviously absolutely useless, except for turning your old, expensive mainframe or supercomputer into a wall clock.

It has also the bonus of running pretty much anywhere: from DOS to Linux to old UNIX systems.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use x11apps in which xclock application as

```
xclock -update 1 -bg lightyellow
```